# Can't use custom Fonts and FontAwesome icons in Custom Controls Library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I'm currently trying to abstractify all my controls by creating a WPF Custom Controls Library, but it doesn't seem to be working. The fonts as well as Font Awesome isn't working, which wasn't a problem when I just styled my controls straight in a "BaseTheme.xaml".

This is my project structure. Enveo is my main project and KalecControlsLibrary is the Custom Controls Library:

[image]

And this is the code in Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KalecControlsLibrary">
<FontFamily x:Key="Ubuntu">pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;Component/Resources/Fonts/#Ubuntu</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;Component/Resources/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;Component/Resources/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular</FontFamily>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Titlebar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Titlebar}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1000">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0"
               Height="25" Width="25" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Source="pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;component/Resources/Icons/Enveo_appicon_transparant_32x32.png"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="enveo" FontWeight="Bold"
                FontSize="16"/>

                        <Button FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" 
                Background="Transparent" Content="&#xf00d;"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Width="40" Height="40"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"
               >
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Background="#EEEEEE"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I don't get is that this isn't working:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="Ubuntu">pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;Component/Resources/Fonts/#Ubuntu</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;Component/Resources/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;Component/Resources/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular</FontFamily>
```

But using an image directly in my Titlebar does work:

```
                        <Image Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0"
               Height="25" Width="25" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Source="pack://application:,,,/KalecControlsLibrary;component/Resources/Icons/Enveo_appicon_transparant_32x32.png"></Image>
```

As you can see, my .png image loads, but the Font Awesome icon doesn't:
[image]